# Getting a input option to happen in all input statements without repeating if/elif/else statments

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, python-3.6

Wondering if there is a way to get python to accept "save" or "s" in a input statement  to do something every time you enter that into any if/elif/else in the .py file, so i don't have to repeat if/elif/else several times. I want some thing like this

```
a=input("some other question that i want to accept s/save: ")
b=input("Again but i dont want 2 if statments: ")
```

rather than.

```
a=input("question: ")
if a == "y":
    print("something")
elif a == "y":
    print("Something")
elif a in ("s", "save")
    print("save")
else:
    print("not option")
print("A bunch of other code for 100 lines")
a=input("question: ")
if a == "y":
    print("something")
elif a == "y":
    print("Something")
elif a in ("s", "save")
    print("save")
else:
    print("not option")
```

and so on through the code

Comment: Try a `dictionary`.

Comment: Isn't this what functions are made for? `def ask_question(): ...`

Comment: ? i dont understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the duplicated code in a function, call the function multiple times:

```
def ask_question(q):
    a=input(q)
    if a == "y":
        print("something")
    elif a == "y":
        print("Something")
    elif a in ("s", "save")
        print("save")
    else:
        print("not option")

# now

ask_question("first question")

print("A bunch of other code for 100 lines")

ask_question("second question")
```

Of course your `ask_question()` needs to be more sophisticated to be useful - e.g. return a value or call other functions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary.

```
a = input("question: ")

a_dict = {'y': 'something', 's': 'save'}

if a in a_dict:
    print(a_dict[a])
else:
    print('not option')
```